# ¿Por qué no me deja importar Tkinter en VScode?

Tags: python, tkinter

VScode me marca "Tkinter" como si no fuera una función ni una librería.

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk() 

windown = Tk()

window.tittle("welcome")

windown.mainloop()
```

Comment: Para que te podamos ayudar mejor, por favor incluye el mensaje de error. Gracias.

Comment: Tu error podría deberse a que usas Python 2.x y haces la importación como si fuera Python 3.x. Prueba cambiando `import tkinter as tk` por `import Tkinter as tk`, notese la t mayuscula en tkinter. Mas información en esta pagina: https://riptutorial.com/tkinter

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos errores en el código:

1. Estas usando la clase Tk() sin haberla importado o instanciado
2. Estas llamando mal al método **title** de la clase Tk

Para solucionar estos errores podrías hacer algo así:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("welcome")
root.mainloop()
```

- Crea la instancia
- Añades un titulo
- Inicias la GUI

Answer (score 0):

esto ocurre cuando no tienes instalada el modulo. la otra opcion es que si hayas instalado el modulo pero en otro interprete como anaconda o un entorno virtual de un proyecto.

instala tkinter con pip install tkinter en la consola de comandos